# Entire function $f$ and a function $g = \overline{f(\bar z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function $f$ and a function $g = \overline{f(\bar z)}$. Then which of the  followings are true.

a)  if $f(z) \in \mathbb R$ for all $z\in \mathbb R$, then $f =g$.

b) if $f(z) \in \mathbb R$ for all $z \in \{  z : Im z =0\}\cup \{z : Im z = a\}$ for some $a>0$, then $f(z+ ia) = f(z - ia)$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$.

c)  if $f(z) \in \mathbb R$ for all $z \in \{  z : Im z =0\}\cup \{z : Im z = a\}$ for some $a>0$, then $f(z+ 2ia) = f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$.

d) if $f(z) \in \mathbb R$ for all $z \in \{  z : Im z =0\}\cup \{z : Im z = a\}$ for some $a>0$, then $f(z+ ia) = f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$.

for a) if $g$ is analytic , then  dfine $h(z) = f(z) - g(z)$ , we get $h(\frac{1}{n}) = 0$, so $0$ is the limit point of zeroes of $h$, then $h =0$, but how to show that $g$ is analytic.

for d), Take $f(z) = e^{z+ \pi i}$, then $f(z + i\pi) = e^{z+ 2i\pi} = e^z$, but $f(z) = e^ze^{i\pi} = -e^z$

I am unable to find any conclusion about a) b) and c).Please help . Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for a), since $f$ is entire, $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ on $\mathbf C$, for some $a_n\in\mathbf C$. Then
$$
g(z)=\overline{f(\overline z)}=\overline{\sum a_n\overline{z}^n}=\sum\overline{a_n\overline{z}^n}=\sum \overline{a_n} z^n
$$
for all $z\in\mathbf C$, by continuity of complex conjugation. Hence, the function $g$ is an entire analytic function. Since $f(z)\in\mathbf R$ for all $z\in\mathbf R$, one has $g=f$ on $\mathbf R$, and $g$ and $f$ coincide on a nondiscrete subset of their common domain. Therefore, $g=f$.

As for b), by a) one has $f=g$, i.e., $f(\overline z)=\overline{f(z)}$ for all $z\in\mathbf C$. Applying a) to the function $z\mapsto f(z-ia)$, one then
also has
$$
f(z-ia)=\overline{f(\overline{z}-ia)}=\overline{f(\overline{z+ia})}=f(z+ia)
$$
for all $z\in\mathbf C$.

As for c), by b) one has $f(z-ia)=f(z+ia)$ for all $z\in\mathbf C$. Substituting $z=w+ia$ one gets $f(w)=f(w+2ia)$ for all $w\in\mathbf C$.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer